# Dialog not working with webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

my application have a webview that when a user don't enter the correct username and password, an alert dialog will pop out and tell him that.

my Webview Interface class is:

```
public class WebAppInterface extends FragmentActivity{
Context mContext;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void showErrorDialog(String text) {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialog();
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "errorDialog");
    }
}
```

and my Dialgofragmenct class is:

```
public class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("שגיאה");
    builder.setMessage("טקסט כלשהו");
    builder.setPositiveButton("אישור", new OnClickListener() {      
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    return builder.create();
}

}
```

the method showErrorDialog() in the interface works when I run the debugger on eclipse, but the application curshes when the method ends, and it doesn't show the alert dialog at all!!!

please help!

Answer (score 0):

showErrorDialog()  should also have @JavascriptInterface if it's method accessible from webview's JavaScript. You don't tell us what rerror prints logcat.

Comment: I added but still it doesn't work, can it be something with the webinterface context can't pass to a dialogFragment?, do you have any more suggestions?